# Who wants the banner of the first regimen?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I picked up that artifact on a planet somewhere. Now there's a mission in my journal saying that I should find someone on the citadel who can use it. I've been running around the place a long time, but I can't seem to find anybody.

Who wants the banner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a group of [Turians](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-3/Apien_Crest:_Banner_of_the_First_Regiment) in the Purgatory bar that will accept the banner.  Doing so will earn you the war asset of the Turian 7th fleet.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a Turian Officer in the Purgatory Bar on the Citadel that wants this banner (see [this quest guide for more information](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-3/Apien_Crest%3A_Banner_of_the_First_Regiment).